# how to change the image when click on selected radio button option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In my php file default image is there. i add some radio button options. here is my code

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="radio" value="<img src='images/image1.jpg'>"><img src="images/image1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"><br/>
<input type="radio" value="<img src='images/image2.jpg'>"><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"><br/>
<input type="radio" value="Both" />Both<br/>
</form>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input:radio[type=radio]").click(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
$('#showoption').html(value);
    });
</script>
 
<label>Value</label>
    /// default image 

<img src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
     <div id="showoption">
     
 
</div>
    </label>
```

When i click on radio button selected image to be showing. I want at the same time default image to be hide. How to solve this issue.

Comment: So currently what is happening and what issue are you facing

Comment: set radio value as image name `image1.jpg` only and onclick radio get the value of checked radio and set it to src tag.

Comment: when i click on radio button selected image is showing but default image is not hide. i want default image hide when i click on radio button.

Comment: add that image in a div and use hide function

Comment: can you please send the total code?

Comment: have an id for the default image and add the below line
$("#idOfdefaultImage").hide();

Comment: i added <div id="color">
   <img src="images/image2.jpg" name="radio" width="50px" height="50px"/>
   </div>  and also in jquery i added $("#idOfdefaultImage").hide();  but default image still showing.

Comment: @narendra, added the code. Please check it if your issue is resolved using that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want like this: changes on in Jquery and add id to your default image.

```html
<style>
.thumbnail img{
width:50px; height:50px;}
</style>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="<img src='images/image1.jpg'>"><img src="images/image1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"><br/>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="<img src='images/image2.jpg'>"><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"><br/>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="Both" />Both<br/>
</form>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input:radio[type=radio]").click(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
$('#showoption').html(value);
$('.defaultImage').hide();
    });
</script>
 
<label>Value</label>
    /// default image 


<div class="defaultImage">
<img src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
</div>
     <div id="showoption" class="thumbnail" style="width:50px;height:50px">
     
 
</div>
    </label>
```

Comment: i want within the class for ex <img id="defaultImage" src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" class="thumbnail"/> in css  .thumbnail{ border:1px solid black;} for default image. i want selected radio button image also follw with same class. is it possible?

Comment: you can also used class instead for id for default image or you can wrap image with div like this <div class="defaultImage><img id="defaultImage" src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" class="thumbnail"/></div> or you can used both and id for image

Comment: I am not getting you what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are, try this code let me if it's fine for you.

```js
$("input:radio[type=radio]").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value == 1)
    {
      $('#image2').hide();
      $('#image1').show();
    }
  else if(value == 2)
    {
      $('#image2').show();
      $('#image1').hide();
    }
  else if(value == 'Both')
    {
      $('#image2').show();
      $('#image1').show();
    }
  
  $('#showoption').html(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  
<input type="radio" name="image" value="1">
  
  
<input type="radio"  name="image" value="2">
  
  
<input type="radio" value="Both"  name="image" />Both<br/>
  
</form>
 

 
<label>Value</label>
    /// default image 

<img src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" id="image2" style="display:none;" alt="image2"/>
<img src="images/image1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" id="image1" style="display:none;" alt="image1"> 
     <div id="showoption">
     
 
</div>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you just want to hide the default image try this code, changes done in jquery :

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="radio" value="<img src='images/image1.jpg'>"><img src="images/image1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"><br/>
<input type="radio" value="<img src='images/image2.jpg'>"><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"><br/>
<input type="radio" value="Both" />Both<br/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input:radio[type=radio]").click(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
$('#showoption').html(value);

$('.def-img').css({'display':'none'}); // this will disappear the image

});
</script>

<label>Value</label>
    // default image 

 <div class="def-img"><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/></div>
 <div id="showoption"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: i want within the class for ex <img id="defaultImage" src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" class="thumbnail"/> in css  .thumbnail{ border:1px solid black;} for default image. i want selected radio button image also follw with same class. is it possible?

Comment: yes it is, so it means there is no default image only that radio button selected image is shown

Comment: @narendra, what is the difference in my and the accepted answer. It is same, still you accepted that answer. And more off I answered much earlier then him.

Comment: <div id="showoption" class="thumbnail" width="50px" height="50px"> i put the same class as per default image. is it correct selected radio button image to be shows within the box?

Comment: @narendra, what are you trying to say it is not clear. And also if not accept you could at least upvote those other answers that solved your issue. As you can accept only single answer.

Comment: @narendra, You didn't mentioned that point earlier. First clear your question then try to ask questions. We all have to answer other questions also. And we all have wasted time in an incomplete question.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the src value on click radio button. and must set radio button name attribute.

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="radio" value="image1.jpg" name="show"><img src="images/image1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"><br/>
<input type="radio" value="image2.jpg" name="show"><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"><br/>
<input type="radio" value="Both" name="show"/>Both<br/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input:radio[type=radio]").click(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
$('#image').attr('src', 'images/'+value);
    });
</script>
<label>Value</label>
<img src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" id="image" />
</label>
```